# Which sander and sandpaper should I use on floor after using wood filler?

Tags: hardwood-floor, sanding, hardwood-refinishing

I've sanded my 100-year-old floor with a drum sander, and troweled wood filler over the entire surface.  Now I'm ready to sand again before staining.  How aggressive of a sander (drum, random orbital) and sand paper/screen should I use for this step?

Thanks!

Comment: Without pictures, it will be hard for anyone to provide an answer.  It really depends on how much excess material you need to remove.  Typical wood filler has characteristics similar to wood, so I would sand it the same way I would if the surface was solid wood.  Just be conservative and vigilant, and judge how aggressive to be based on the results you get.

Comment: I agree with fixer1234 filler should be sanded similar to the other areas but it will almost never look the same as unfilled wood because of the different material when putting new stain down or an oil finish.